# How to select a different module to run when you click the Run button in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

In my IntelliJ IDEA project, I have 3 modules written in Kotlin:

1. An HTTP Servlet one.
2. A desktop swing application; and
3. A library that contains contracts that the above two listed projects share to talk to each other.

When I click the **Run** button, it starts the Tomcat server and loads up my servlet project. That is because, and I am guessing here, the new project creation template inside of the IDE created a new **Run Configuration** for the entire project and it is defined in this run configuration that it must start the module that has the servlet inside it.

Now that the servlet runs fine, I'd like to also run the desktop application written using Swing.

How do I do that? I've done this once before but I have forgotten how I did it.

Do I have to define a new **Run Configuation**? I tried that this way:

[image]

I selected **Kotlin** from the left pane titled **Add New Configuration** and specified the name of the class that had the `main` function, and also the name of the module that had this class.

Here is the source code of my `main` class.

```
package bookyard.client;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Program {

    public fun main(args : Array<String>) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(LoginDialogEventLoop());

    }
}
```

But when I click the **Run** button after choosing that run configuration's name, the process reports an error that suggests that the class name I specified as having the `main` function actually does not have the `main` function, which I am not sure why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` method needs to be static, and the method you have declared is not. In Kotlin, you can either declare `main` as a top-level function (outside of a class), or, if you want to keep it inside the class, use the following syntax:

```
class Program {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String) { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of that but it's funny because my code worked as it is in Eclipse. I first wrote the whole thing in Eclipse in Java, then in Eclipse in Kotlin and now am porting it to IntelliJ IDEA. I had to, in the process, refactor most static methods that were earlier in Java classes into the global namespace as just independent functions in Kotlin but not for the `main`.  contd...

Comment: The `main` ran just fine inside the `Program` class as an instance method in Eclipse. I also looked up and tried adding the @platformStatic annotation to the `main` method inside an *object declaration* called `Program` instead of having the class `Program` but IntelliJ was not happy with that either. Your suggestion works fine, though.

Comment: The `@platformStatic` annotation existed only in pre-release versions of Kotlin. If you found its mentions in some documentation or samples, you should be aware that they are out of date.